# Debug Assertion Failed (unsigned)(c+1) <= 256 (in VideoCapture::open [Qt Creator])

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, qt4, qt-creator

I've been trying to use **cv::VideoCapture::open("< path to video file >")** in **QtCreator** (opencv added). Even though the program **runs without errors in "bebug mode"** (debug build), it gives below **runtime error in "release mode"** (release build).

> Debug Assertion Failed File:
>   f:/dd/vctools/crt_bld/self_x86/src/isctype.c Line: 56 Expression:
>   (unsigned)(c+1) <= 256

It is a simple program which uses only cv::VideoCapture::open() [for testing purposes]

**Below is the .pro file**

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
TARGET = untitled
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp   
HEADERS  += mainwindow.h   
FORMS    += mainwindow.ui   

INCLUDEPATH += C:/C/opencv/build/include
INCLUDEPATH += C:/C/opencv/build/include/opencv  

LIBS += C:/C/opencv/build/x86/vc10/lib/opencv_highgui240d.lib
LIBS += C:/C/opencv/build/x86/vc10/lib/opencv_highgui240.lib


LIBS += C:/C/opencv/build/x86/vc10/bin/opencv_highgui240d.dll
LIBS += C:/C/opencv/build/x86/vc10/bin/opencv_highgui240.dll
```

**Below is the Header file**

```
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    cv::VideoCapture vcap;
};
```

**Below is the .cpp file**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    vcap.open("C:/Users/ANURUDDHA/pedestrians/ThreePastShop2cor.mpg");
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

**When I pass an `int` as the argument to cv::VideoCapture::open() [eg: vcap.open(0)] it runs without errors in both debug and release build and opens webcam successfully. Problem comes only when I pass a String to arguments.**

Someone please shed some light on this. Really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I found the answer though it seems kinda ambiguous to me. Anyway, now the program works in release mode. 
Hope this might help someone in someway.

I copied dll files inside C:/C/opencv/build/x86/vc10/bin/ to Windows system folder. That is C:\Windows\SysWOW64. In case if someone is using a 32 bit version of Windows it should be System32.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're linking in both debug and release versions of the libs (twice?).  That's caused me problems in the past before.  Try using only `LIBS += C:/C/opencv/build/x86/vc10/bin/opencv_highgui240.dll` for release builds and `LIBS += C:/C/opencv/build/x86/vc10/bin/opencv_highgui240d.dll` for debug builds.

Also, 0 is the same as NULL.  Probably the library aborts doing whatever it was doing (whether in debug or release) prior to the assert fail.  You shouldn't be getting assert fails in release mode, but the fact that you are tells me that the debug library was loaded in your program that you compiled for release mode.

**Edit:**

Looks like somebody already answered you here:
http://answers.opencv.org/question/15838/videocaptureopenqt-creatordebug-assertion-failed/

Comment: Thanks for response Peter. Yes, I did included them separately as you have suggested.

But when I used `LIBS += C:/C/opencv/build/x86/vc10/bin/opencv_highgui240.dll` it ended up with this; **The program has unexpectedly finished.
C:\Users\ANURUDDHA\C++\untitled\release\untitled.exe exited with code -1073741515**. I experienced this when builder couldn't find correct lib.

Comment: Let me add some thing, please. The above mentioned error came when I used only `LIBS += C:/C/opencv/build/x86/vc10/bin/opencv_highgui240.dll` in **release build**.
When I used only `LIBS += C:/C/opencv/build/x86/vc10/bin/opencv_highgui240d.dll` in **debug build** no such error occurred. Program ran successfully.

Can't figure out why the program cannot find `opencv_highgui240.dll` in release build. (If that's what makes the problem).

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Qt Creator, but both on MinGW and VC++ compilers and linkers, I've not had to specify the DLL file as a lib-- just the lib file.  Have you tried removing the `LIB += C:/C/opencv/build/x86/vc10/bin/opencv_highgui240.dll` for release (and for debug too)?  AFAIK, linking to the .lib tells the program  all it needs to know about the content of the DLL it needs to know at runtime.  Also, in your release build, is the right DLL located in the same directory as the release-built exe?

Comment: Peter, thanks again for the response.
Removing `LIB += C:/C/opencv/build/x86/vc10/bin/opencv_highgui240.dll` didn't really help.
Previously dll was not included in the directory where exe resides. I copied dll (`opencv_highgui240.dll`) into the working dir. But didn't solve the problem.

What interests me is that, program executes fine when I pass 0 to VideoCapture(). That is `vcap.open(0);`. Error comes only when a String is passed to it. That is `vcap.open("C:/Users/ANURUDDHA/pedestrians/ThreePastShop2cor.mpg");`.

Comment: VideoCapture() should take both int and String ([explained in opencv docs](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#cv-videocapture-videocapture)), but don't know why it aborts when a String is passed..